# How to set coordinate of point other than default?

Tags: android, andengine

I have a semicircle sprite . Now the default way to set it's coordinates are `sprite.setX()` , `sprite.setY()` . What I want is to do is **set** the coordinate of a point other than the default top left corner . Namely , I want to set the local coordinate of `(0,getHeight(piece)/2)` to some coordinate of the scene .

Now , I can **get** the coordinates of that point by :-

```
final float[] endCoordinate = this.convertLocalToSceneCoordinates(0, mPiece1.getHeight());
```

and use these coordinates other places in game.

But , I can't find anywhere on how to set the coordinate of a point other than the top left corner coordinates .

Now I know I can do `setX(setingvalueX) , setY(setingvaluY - mPiece1.getHeight())` , but in my situation I need to set the other point explicitly .

Comment: You best bet is to add a method to your sprite, which would do the translation for you.

Comment: You mean I create a new Class that extends Sprite and add a function to it ? Could you give me an idea as to how the function would be ? Thanks !

Comment: All you need to do is to override `setY` method: `public void setY(int valueY) { super.setY(valueY - getHeight()); }` - or something to that effect.

Comment: Yeah , I understand what you are saying . Btw , This sprite also rotates . So it won't always be (0 , valueY-getHeight()) . But I will make it for the 4 cases (cause it rotates by 90 degrees) . Thanks anyways , I am new to this . Possibly a ready made function would have made things easier . I wanted to add images to better explain the complete situation but can't do it before 10 reputation.